# Elasticsearch pagination of documents on their nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have a document with people and their friends and i want to perform different searches, with pagination on their nested documents. I've tried to find this but haven't really located any solution for the problem.

So it's actually the second and third example that i'm trying to solve.

**Data:**

```
[
 {"id":1,"friends": [{"id":11,"name":"A"}, {"id":12,"name": "B"}]},
 {"id":2,"friends": [{"id":21,"name":"A"}, {"id":22,"name": "C"}]},
 {"id":3,"friends": [{"id":31,"name":"A"}, {"id":32,"name": "C"}, {"id":33,"name":"A"}]}
]
```

**1. Find all friends**

```
[
  {"id":11,"name":"A"}, {"id":12,"name": "B"}, 
  {"id":21,"name":"A"}, {"id":22,"name": "C"}, 
  {"id":31,"name":"A"}, {"id":32,"name": "C"}, {"id":33,"name":"A"}
]
```

**2. Find all friends size 3**

```
[
  {"id":11,"name":"A"}, {"id":12,"name": "B"}, 
  {"id":21,"name":"A"}
]
```

**3. Find all friends size 3, from 4**

```
[
  {"id":22,"name": "C"}, 
  {"id":31,"name":"A"}, {"id":32,"name": "C"}
]
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. They are related to different parents right? "11" and "12" are friends of "1" while "21" and "22" are friends of "2", right? The problem is inner hits are associated with root document.

Comment: Maybe not the best example, but yes, the inner hits associated with the root element. And I would prefer not to handle this as parent-child relationship

Comment: @J2B did you figure out the answer to this?

Comment: @Ouroboros I don't remember, and haven't been working with elastic for 2 years but I think I made a split in the documents. One for the parent and one the children. And if I remember correctly that is also the recommended way in the documentation